# GUI.Toggle button in Unity does not close pop up window

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine, popupwindow, unityscript

I have the following script to open a GUI.Window as a pop up with a toggle button. In Unity3d editor player the script run o.k., with the window open-close on toggle button click. 
As I compile the scene to my Android device, the script runs, but I can only open the GUI.Window with touching toggle button, and I cannot close it on touching again the button.

Take a look at the script, and give me some advise why is that happening, **what is wrong with this UnityScript?**  Thank you all in advance.

Here is the script:

```
#pragma strict
private var doWindow0 : boolean = false;
var aTexture : Texture;
var wTexture : Texture;

// Make the contents of the window.
function DoWindow0 (windowID : int) {
    GUI.color = Color.cyan;     
    GUI.Box (new Rect (10,10,415,210),wTexture);

}

function OnGUI () {
    if(!aTexture) {
        Debug.LogError("Please assign a texture in the inspector.");
        return;
    }
    // Make a toggle button for hiding and showing the window

    doWindow0 = GUI.Toggle(Rect(210,210,70,20), doWindow0, aTexture);
    //doWindow0 = GUI.Button (new Rect (10,10,100,20), doWindow0, "InfoBox");

    // Make sure we only call GUI.Window if doWindow0 is true.
    if (doWindow0)
        GUI.Window (0, Rect (30,0,420,215), DoWindow0, "InfoBox");

    // Make the windows be draggable.
    GUI.DragWindow (Rect (0,0,10000,10000));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since nobody has posted anything yet, let me crarify the situation. After extented research with "trial and error" and step by step running (& debuging) the posted script, I have finaly made it, to find the culprit.

There was nothing wrong in the js code. It was a GameObject, the device rendered on a lower layer, besides the layer of the toggle button.

It seems that the graphics chip of my android device, isn't strong enough to render 2d and 3d graphic simultaneously with user interaction. Having replaced the 3d GameObject with a high definition 2d image, made everything work ok.